# ReportLab: Text with large font size is crammed within paragraph

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab, paragraph

Using ReportLab, I want to render a block of text with a large font size.  Right now, my code places the text within a Paragraph so it can be word wrapped.  However, the text turns out crammed together when rendered.

It seems like the height I specified for the Paragraph object is not being taken into account.  Is there an attribute for Paragraph that I can add to fix this?

My Code Below:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch 
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from  reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER

doc = canvas.Canvas('test.pdf')
p = ParagraphStyle('test')
p.textColor = 'black'
p.borderColor = 'black'
p.borderWidth = 1
p.alignment = TA_CENTER
p.fontSize = 100

para = Paragraph("THIS IS A REALLY LONG AND BIG STRING OF TEXT RIGHT HERE!!!!!", p)
para.wrapOn(doc,1200,1000)
para.drawOn(doc, 0.5*inch, 6*inch)
doc.save()
```

Comment: Maybe this should help: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to set the leading attribute to 120:

```
p.leading = 120
```

By default, a style has a fontSize of 10 with a leading value of 12. The leading parameter specifies the distance down to move when advancing from one text line to the next.